# curiouser & curiouser: mutate() lreaches inside of function defining new column, says its arguments unused

Tags: r, parsing, scope, dplyr

The code below is intended to divide the data into quantiles (with wtd.quantile from Frank Harrell"s Hmisc, use the quantiles and the data (+ a little jitter) to define a factor (with cut) and then group on the factor to find means of the between-quantile groups. However, I get this "missing arguments" error, reproduced below, not from wtd.quantile as I would expect, but from mutate. Is this being parsed wrong? Or is it some completely different problem?

```
library(Hmisc)
library(dplyr)
year    <- c(10,10,20,20,30,30)
hhinc99 <- c(101,102,301,302,501,502)
wtsupp  <- c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.5,1.7,1.11)
midy    <- tibble(year, hhinc99, wtsupp)

midy  %>% 
  group_by(year)   %>% 
  mutate(inc2 = hhinc99, 
         inc_q_groups = cut(inc2, 
                breaks = wtd.quantile(hhinc99 + .Machine$double.eps * 100 * rnorm(length(hhinc99)), 
                           weights = wtsupp, probs=c(0, 0.5, 1))))                   %>% 
         group_by(inc_q_groups)                                                    %>% 
         summarise(inc_q_means = 
                   wtd.mean(hhinc99, weights = wtsupp, na.rm=TRUE))  ->  inc_dec_means

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: unused arguments (weights = wtsupp, probs = c(0, .5. 1)).
```

If I pull out just the quantile function and attach midy, I get:>

```
breaks
  0%  50% 100% 
 101  302  502
```

This problem just keeps getting stranger. If I just replace mutate with dplyr::mutate above, and change nothing else, I get this error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor".
```

Usually I would take that as a sign of package conflicts. But who else uses "mutate"? I think that's a Hadley special. getAnywhere shows a copy of mutate in the plyr namespace, which I suppose could be different, but I don't have plyr loaded.

All comments, thoughts, answers, suggestions, etc. welcome.

Comment: you have a misplaced parenthesis, it shows directly when copy pasting in R studio : `rnorm(length(hhinc99))` and remove it on next line. then you'll get a new error to play with ;)

Comment: That's right Moody, thanks for the catch. I somehow introduced that when copying it here. I have corrected the parenthesis above; the error on the corrected is as I originally stated.

Comment: The error I get now is `Evaluation error: 'breaks' are not unique.`

Comment: Moody, I keep correcting the probs argument, which makes your error go away and mine appear, and it keeps not taking--only just went through. Don't know why. Sorry. But note additional info above: the wtd.quantile function is not the culprit. And strangely, I get yet another error if I just replace mutate with dplyr::mutate. I don't know why that should do anything.

Comment: Probably because you load package `plyr` after `dplyr`. If like many users you use `dplyr` much more I suggest you never load `plyr` and always use the `plyr::some_function` form. `mutate` is not the only conflictual function, `summarize` is in both packages too for example

Comment: That is a reasonable suspicion. But I have checked, and I don't have plyr loaded, even by another package. I am baffled by this..

Comment: I keep having edits I make revert. This looks right to me now, but just in case, there should be 4 right parentheses after the mutate and 2 right parenthesis after the summarize

Comment: You might be interested by package `reprex` (possibly only on github)